# Unable to capture onClick events on Marker's children included in deck.gl@^7.1.10

Tags: reactjs, onclick, marker, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I used deck.gl@^6.4.7 and react-map-gl@^5.0.7, and I had placed a Marker with an icon children that was listening on click events. 
When I updated the deck.gl to version 7.1.10, the icon's click events stopped working.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

```
        <DeckGL
          initialViewState={{
            longitude: liveMapZoom.lng,
            latitude: liveMapZoom.lat,
            zoom: 12,
            bearing: 0,
            pitch: 0
          }}
          viewState={viewState}
          onClick={(info, event) => {
            console.log("info", info);
            console.log("event", event);
          }}
          onViewStateChange={this._onViewStateChange}
          controller={{ type: MapController, dragRotate: false }}
          layers={[
            layerCars(data)
          ]}
        >
          <ReactMapGL
            mapStyle={"mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"}
            mapboxApiAccessToken={TOKEN}
          >
           <Marker
             key={key}
             latitude={coordinates[1]}
             longitude={coordinates[0]}
            >
              <img
                alt={name}
                src={iconUrl}
                onClick={event => {
                  console.log("hey");
                }}
              />
            </Marker>
          </ReactMapGL>
        </DeckGL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution to the previous issue, so I changed Markers to Icon layers.

Comment: It did for me, but you can check this out as well https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/issues/3389

Comment: What is `MapController`

Comment: I didn't saw any onClick prop in iconLayer in `deck.gl`

Comment: It is not referred to in the documentation, but you can use the onClick event in IconLayer. Make sure you have added "pickable: true" as well